# Modify bar progress style in ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to re-design ChartJS to be like this:

[Preview of desired ChartJS Bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zllr.png)

I have issues with the following parts:

1. I tried to use the default bar chart, but I'm not sure how to make the table like this, I mean I can put a grid background, but how do I make a title beside every column?
2. How do I make a shape between 2 bars? in light purple color
3. How do make a constant tooltip beside each bar?

I tried to use the default bar chart: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/border-radius.html